# How can i use this woocommerce product accordion without loading parent product category first?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
 * WooCommerce Product List as accordion (BS5)
 */
function ct_render_cat_list()
{
    global $wp_query;
    $current_cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    $current_term_id = null;
    $current_parent_id = isset($current_cat->term_id) ? $current_cat->term_id : null;
    if (!is_null($current_parent_id)) {
        if ($current_cat->parent != 0) {
            $current_parent_id = $current_cat->parent;
        }
        $current_term_id = $current_cat->term_id;
    }
    /**
     * Product categories list
     */
    $args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => true,
        'parent' => 0,
    );
    $product_cat = get_terms($args);

    echo '<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">';
    foreach ($product_cat as $parent_product_cat) {
        $parent_id = $parent_product_cat->term_id;
        // skip 'Uncategorized'
        if ($parent_product_cat->term_id == '15') {
            continue;
        }
        $button = '
                  <a class="accordion-button collapsed text-decoration-none" href="' . get_term_link($parent_product_cat->term_id) . '">
                    ' . $parent_product_cat->name . ' (' . $parent_product_cat->count . ')
                  </a>
            ';
        if ($parent_id == $current_parent_id) {
            $button = '<button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse' . $parent_id . '" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse' . $parent_id . '">
                       ' . $parent_product_cat->name . ' (' . $parent_product_cat->count . ')
                    </button>';
        }
        echo '
<div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
        ' . $button . '
    </h2>
          ';
        if ($parent_id == $current_parent_id) {
            $child_args = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'hide_empty' => false,
                'parent' => $parent_product_cat->term_id
            );
            $child_product_cats = get_terms($child_args);
            if (!empty($child_product_cats)) :
                echo '<div id="collapse' . $parent_id . '" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="accordion-body"> ';
                echo "<ul class='navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-md-0 '>";
                foreach ($child_product_cats as $child_product_cat) {
                    $active_class = '';
                    if ($current_term_id == $child_product_cat->term_id) {
                        $active_class = 'active';
                    }
                    echo '<li class="nav-item"><a href="' . get_term_link($child_product_cat->term_id) . '" class="nav-link link-dark ' . $active_class . '">' . $child_product_cat->name . ' (' . $child_product_cat->count . ')</a></li>';
                }
                echo '</ul>';
                echo '</div>
                </div> <!-- / accordion-collapse -->';
            endif;
        }
        echo '</div> <!-- accordion-item -->';
    }
    echo '</div> <!-- / accordion -->';
}
```

Here is the code for showing product categories as accordion. The problem here for me is that if i want to open the accordion, i first have to load the $parent_product_cat but i want to use the accordion without loading it and show me dropdown right away. At the moment the main category on page is anchor tags and they will change to buttons when main category is loaded. Hope you'll get my point :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: (https://avallone.ee/tectronyx/shop/)

This is the page, as you can see there are product categories on the left sidebar. For example there is "KANGE ALKOHOL" (strong alcohol). When i click on that, it will load the page and the URL will be "(https://avallone.ee/tectronyx/product-category/kange-alkohol/)" and after that i can use the dropdown menu. I want to use it without loading the main category or even better, when click on the icon then open accordion and when click on the name then the main category.

For example, like on this page - (https://avallone.ee/tooted/)